# Не работают кнопки в Canvas Unity3d

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

У меня есть две сцены, одна только с **GUI**, другая сама игра. Нужно при нажатии на кнопку перейти в сцену игры. Если обе сцены активны, то отображается и GUI и игра.
Решил загрузить сцену с игрой, тогда **GUI** перестаёт работать - кнопки не нажимаются.

### Собственно вопрос:

**Почему при загрузке сцены с игрой кнопки в меню не работают?**

Comment: Без хотя бы кода на этот вопрос невозможно ответить.

Answer (score 0):

1. Я советую меню подгружать в саму сцену (только если меню НЕ главное. Если главное - отдельный левел)
2. GUI и UI в юнити это разные вещи. То что в канвасе -- это UI.
3. Могу предположить что в коде ты отключал тот или иной обьект меню. При отключении он выгружается из памяти, а так же все скрипты его перестают работать. Так устроена оптимизация. Но это просто пальцем в небо ибо кода здесь нет, не на что опираться.
4. Я не знаю что такое "обе сцены активны". У тебя или одна сцена или вторая может быть активной. Сразу две сцены активными быть не могут. Или один левел подгружен или второй.

Comment: сцены можно загружать аддитивно) Тогда они обе будут активны

Answer (score 0):

Если прорисовка интерфейса идет через UI, то возможно у вас в сцене нет объекта EventSystem. В таком случае события по UI не будут обрабатываться.

Второй вариант у вас есть на сцене в UI второй Canvas в котором расположена одна картинка на весь экран, прозрачная которая перехватывает все ваши нажатия.

Проверяйте что ни одна из этих проблем у вас не проявляется.